# Is it possible that an insert to the remote MySQL succeeds but fails to report that to the client?

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible that my code, which inserts stuff to a remote MySQL server executes the query successfully (new row appears in the remote table), but after that the network fails and the response from the server doesn't get delivered to the script, to which it would look as if the insert failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's possible.  Nothing about failing to deliver the response to the client would prevent the server from successfully completing the operation, assuming of course that "autocommit" is on or the like.

Comment: But then even wrapping the insert into a transaction (e.g. no autocommit) will not guarantee that the script gets the response?

Comment: No, I don't think you can 100% guarantee you will get a response.  All you can do with a transaction is to be sure the operation doesn't happen (since you won't `commit`) unless you get a response from the `insert`.

Comment: So the only reliable way to make sure duplicate data isn't inserted is to add some kind of a unique index?